# Accordion active

Tags: jquery, accordion, wizard

I am using jQuery accordion as step by step wizard to enter user information.

---

->  Account Information

---

->  Personal Information

---

-> Additional Info

---

When user clicks next button in "Account Info", "Personal Info" div must open.
What I am currently doing is, destroying the accordion and recreating it.

$("#Accordion").destroy().accordion({active: "#Personal", collapsible:true, autoHeight: false, header: "> div > h3"});

Is there a way to activate "personal information" without recreating the accordion?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Use the option setter method: $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 ); Check documentation for more details: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Comment: Thanks Milanzor! 
I thought $("#Accordion").accordion("option","active",2) would also initiate the accordion. And that I should destroy the accordion before setting options. 
Silly me! Please enter this as ans so that I can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the option setter method:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Check documentation for more details: api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active